# VB6 Form Modality : Runtime Error #5

Tags: vb6, modality

VB6

I'm trying to display a non modal Form from a non modal form, but upon calling the `.Show` method, i keep getting a `run-time error #5`.

This is only happening when the .exe is compiled and does not occur in the IDE.

Anyone else run into a situation like this before?

Comment: How could you have a modal form in the background?

Comment: I think we may need to see more of your code.  Do you have something in your `Form_Load` event of the form that you are trying to call the `Show` method against?